# php if condition not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

For the below page:
https://www.mousampictures.com/department/wedding/

I am trying to show an slider if the heading matches the provided heading:

```
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <div class="layout-full">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
           <!-- This displays 'Wedding' -->
            </header>

            <!-- wedding -->        
            <?php 
                if ( single_cat_title() == "Wedding")  {
//above line doesn't work...and instead prints wedding on the page.
                    echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="1710"]');
                }
            ?>

            <!--portrait -->
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="1718"]'); ?> 

            <!--travel -->
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="1714"]'); ?>

        </div>
```

I need to show each slider, depending on the correct page.

Comment: Did you check `single_cat_title()` returned exactly `Wedding` and that it does not contain a space or some other minor difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two optional parameters to include in the `single_cat_title()` function as per the documentation (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/).

[image]

Try setting the second parameter (`$display`) to `FALSE`:

```
if ( single_cat_title('', FALSE) == "Wedding")  {
    echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="1710"]');
}
```

Without setting this value you are indicating that the title should be displayed, set this to false to retrieve it instead of display it.

Comment: `if(!strcasecmp(single_cat_title('', FALSE), "wedding"))`

Answer (score 1):

The function single_cat_title, by default prints the title, if you want to retrieve the value for comparison you need to use the function ins a distinct way.

On the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/) for the function, you can see the definition:

```
single_cat_title( string $prefix = '', bool $display = true )
```

Meaning, on your case you should do the following if condition:

```
if ( single_cat_title('', false) == "Wedding")  {
```

By using the second parameter to false, you will get the desired value instead of having it printed out.

Answer (score 1):

`single_cat_title()` takes two parameters, `prefix` which defaults to an empty string and `display` which is a boolean and defaults to `true`.

Change your conditional to this format:

```
if ("Wedding" == single_cat_title("", false)) {
    // do something
}
```